# problem with a user interface in roblox studio

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

i made a settings gui for the player to cut off the music or turn it on and the only problem is that the gui is by default showing

i tried moving the code or setting true to false... but nothing worked, i will addd the code below

```
local open = true

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if open == true then
        open = false
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.MainFrame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.278, 0,0.319, 0), "InOut", "Quad", 0.5, true)
    else
        open = true
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.MainFrame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.278, 0,1, 0), "InOut", "Quad", 0.5, true)
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you showing the GUI to the player?

- If you put it in StarterGui, the game will automatically handle this by cloning the GUI to the player's PlayerGui folder, which will automatically show the GUI.
- If you did it yourself, you might forget that the ScreenGui is enabled and shows upon being cloned to the player's PlayerGui folder.

This also means subsequent frames that have their .Visibile property turned on, will also automatically be shown.

All in all, it means that the GUI is set to show itself first thing it's parented.

To solve this you might want your localscript to also control the appropiate properties of the ScreenGui and frames you want to show.

E.g.

```lua
local mainFrame = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.MainFrame
local open = true

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if open == true then
        open = false
        mainFrame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.278, 0,0.319, 0), "InOut", "Quad", 0.5, true)
        task.wait(0.5)
        mainFrame.Visible = false
    else
        open = true
        mainFrame.Visible = true
        mainFrame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.278, 0,1, 0), "InOut", "Quad", 0.5, true)
    end
end)
```

Of course, there also might be the start position of the frame isn't properly set causing the issue you currently have. You'd have to either set it in the GUI editing mode, or at the start of a localscript:

```lua
...
mainFrame.Position = UDim2.new(0.278, 0,0.319, 0)
...
-- the rest of the code
...
```